# Jquery Animate Issue with Draggable Item

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a jquery script to swap draggable items locations but for some reason the animate effect causes visual issues during the swap. The script is a variation of codef0rmer's jsfiddle that I've made a few changes to to fit my needs. I created a jsfiddle to show the issue, currently I've located the problem coming from the swap function and have commented out the line that works but doesnt animate. If anyone can help me with getting the swap to animate correctly I'd greatly appreciate it. You can view the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AywmJ/161/

This is function that the issue is originating from (I believe):

```
  function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
           $el.animate({fromPos, toPos}, duration, callback || $.noop);
           //(callback || $.noop)();
        }
```

Comment: I updated my jquery along with the jsfiddle link but I'm still encountering the same problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"visual issues during the swap"_ as to exactly what visual issues is the swap causing?

Comment: When swapping positions of the elements the dragged pin will animate from an incorrect direction to take its place during the swap. If you take a peek at the jsfiddle and try to drag a pin onto another pin you can see the issue during the swap.

Comment: What's exaclty you want to animate? If i drag A over B you want to animate B going into A's old place?

Comment: Correct, spot on Luca!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with jquery-animation, but I found few thing to fix the swap issue.

When you drag placeholder("div tag with draggable class") its adding syle properties `style="position: relative; z-index: auto; left: 151px; top: 22px;"` with  **`left: 151px; top: 22px`**, meaning how far the placeholder has moved from current position with left and top attributes.

In the current code you are `swapping .draggable placeholders`, that's why you are seeing that unusual behavior

Instead swap the content of .draggable

```
<div class="pinChildContainer droppable">
      <div class="pins draggable">
            <img class="pinImage" src="img/paymentServices.jpg" alt="Payment Services" width="188" height="185" />
            <p class="pinTitle">Payment Services</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Change  to (now swap .pins)

```
<div class="pinChildContainer droppable">
      <div class="draggable">
            <div class="pins">
                  <img class="pinImage" src="img/paymentServices.jpg" alt="Payment Services" width="188" height="185" />
                  <p class="pinTitle">Payment Services</p>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for swapping .pins

```
var dragged = $(ui.draggable);
var fromContainer = dragged.parent();
var toContainer = $(this);
var displaced = $(this).find('.pins');

// added class .from and .to classes to identify the placeholders
var fromPinContainer = dragged.find('.pins').removeClass('from to');
fromPinContainer.addClass("from");

displaced.removeClass('from to');
displaced.addClass("to");

if (fromContainer.is(toContainer)) {
    dragged.animate({ left: 0, top: 0 });
}

dragged.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 });
displaced.animate({ bottom: 0, left: 0 }, finalize);

function finalize() {
   fromContainer.find('.draggable').append(toContainer.find('.to'));
   toContainer.find('.draggable').append(dragged.find('.from'));
}

finalize();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AywmJ/163/)

I guess it's not polished code, but it gives the effect of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Pavan, I greatly appreciate it!